# Hide wrapper <div> when video ends

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have an html div containing a video;

```
<body>
<div id="loginVideoLayer" class="loginvideoLayer">

    <video id="loginVideo" height="100%" width="100%" autoplay muted onEnded="videoEnded()">

        <source src="Videos/Log\_in.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>

</div>
</body>
```

and the following script which I want to hide the entire div when the video ends;

```
<script>
function videoEnded() {

  var x = document.getElementById("loginVideoLayer");

  if (x.style.display === "block") {

x.style.display = "none";

  } else {

x.style.display = "block";

  }
</script>
```

But when the video ends it simply goes black. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You tagged `jquery`, do you want a JavaScript solution or a jQuery solution?

Comment: Also nothing looks incorrect here. Do you see any errors in console, maybe not for this script but others that might be a showstopper?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an else statement. When your video is ended. It's ended and displayed as none. what is the else suppose to do? nothing.

**Your problem:** Your video is on autoplay calls the function first time it ended. goes hidden then the video starts and ends again (while hidden) then come back to `display:block`

so basically your code shall be as simple as:

```
function videoEnded() {
  var x = document.getElementById("loginVideoLayer");
  x.style.display = "none";
  }
```

unless you want to bring back your video to life after a time.